# change command line values from another file using os.system

Tags: python, python-2.7

First part of the code is in a file names loop.py that I want to run in the second file names as loop2.py. I want to assign the value 12,15,17 to the lattice_size while running the file loop2.py. How can I do that?

**code for `loop.py`**

```
import argparse
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--lattice_size', '-ls',default=4, type=int, help='lattice')
FLAGS=p.parse_args()
print ("Lattice size is %d" % (FLAGS.lattice_size))`
```

**code for `loop2.py`**

```
import os
import sys
os.system("python loop.py")`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through those arguments, you should be able to use:

```
import os
results = []
for ls in [12, 15, 17]:
    result = os.system('python loop.py --lattice_size %s' % str(ls))
    results.append(result)
```

This should work for Python 2.7 or 3.x.

You might also want to look into using [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead. It is supposed to be a bit safer, and more feature-rich, although I am less familiar with the syntax for Python 2.7.

```
import subprocess
results = []
for ls in [12, 15, 17]:
    command = ['python', 'loop.py', '--lattice_size', str(ls)]
    result = subprocess.call(command)
    results.append(result)  # make list of results
    print(result)
```

Comment: okay thanks. But how this can be done with os.system command? I want to use os.system

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just use `os.system('python loop.py --lattice_size {}'.format(ls))` in that loop. But ask yourself why you want to use `os`, and check out the [`subprocess` PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/#rationale). `subprocess` is basically just better, unless you have a good reason to prefer `os`.

Comment: I repeated the updated answer but it is giving me the error that syntax is invalid

Comment: Sorry, typo in my argument, should be `--lattice_size`; I only had one "t". It works on my machine.

Comment: python: can't open file 'loop.py,': [Errno 2] No such file or directory now I'm getting this error. I am using exactly same command

Comment: Are `loop.py` and `loop2.py` in the same directory? If not, you need to give `os.system` the relative (or full) path to `loop.py`, otherwise how could it know where to find it?

Comment: they are in the same directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171708/discussion-between-engineero-and-sara).